# Can't change default icon of TaskpaneButton to custom image

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, manifest, office-js, office-addins

I've faced with problem while trying to change standart icon to custom for  TaskpaneButton on the ribbon of Office Word 2016.

I've added the specific images (Size: 16X16, 32X32, 80X80) to my project solution
and changed path to images in manifest.

```
  <!-- Control. It can be of type "Button" or "Menu". -->
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton">
              <Label resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
              <Supertip>
                <!-- ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
                <Title resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                <!-- ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource. -->
                <Description resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16"/>
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32"/>
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80"/>
              </Icon>  
            </Control>
          </Group>
        </OfficeTab>
      </ExtensionPoint>
    </DesktopFormFactor>
  </Host>
</Hosts> 
<Resources>
  <bt:Images>
    <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_16x16"
              DefaultValue="http://localhost:1234/wa/Images/R16X16.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_32x32"
              DefaultValue="http://localhost:1234/wa/Images/R32X32.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_80x80"
              DefaultValue="http://localhost:1234/wa/Images/R80X80.png"/>
  </bt:Images>
```

But I see the default (blue hexagon)  image after adding addin into the ribbon.

Btw. I've checked this in office online and mac versions It works fine and I can see my icons instead of default icons.

Also I've cleaned the caches of Office using "Office Upload Center" tool but the result is the same.

Can anyone to explain the main reason of this issue?

Comment: How are you deploying your add-in? Visual Studio? Sideloading via fileshare?  Did you press refresh on the add-ins dialog?

Comment: Hi, I've used fileshare. I've put manifest into share folder and insert this one from "Insert" tab in Word addin

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **httpS** to host the icons. Some platforms are more lax and don't enforce the requirement which is why you might see it working right now in Online.